# Android equalsIgnoreCase not working correctly

Tags: java, android, string, equals

temp1 is "accountant"editText is "accountant"

but i checked with String.length();

- temp1 is a string has 11 characters  editText has 10 characters

I tried trim() method, i got the same result again.

Code sample:

```
    if(temp1.equalsIgnoreCase(editText1.getText().toString().trim()))
      {
        //do someting
      }
```

I solved.

- I coverted source file to UTF-8 with "Notepad++" and get words from new source file. EqualsIgnoreCase works now.

Comment: Check if there any white spaces are in temp1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `temp1` is a string and has 11 characters, you must have placed a whitespace after the word accountant. (Either that or you flat out misspelled the word.) Accountant is only 10 characters long, so there must be whitespace. (Well, it's pretty guaranteed since you, yourself, created it.)

Either remove the whitespace from `temp1`, or trim `temp1` before you compare.
Also, double-check `temp1` to actually make sure you spelled the word correctly.

Comment: Certainly , as you say i created. How to remove the whitespace ? I tried replaceAll method. It didnt work.

Comment: replaceAll("\\s","") should do the trick. Are you sure there isn't something else you've done to your String? It seems odd that the replaceAll method isn't getting rid of any potential whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this code :

```
    //put this below public class activity

    int index=0; 
    String [] answer ={"Accountant"};
```

and put this button code below setContentView

```
buttonanswer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.yourbutton);
buttonanswer.setOnClickListener(this);
```

and then put this code

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {               

    edittextanswer=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.youreditText); 
    if(v==buttonanswer) {

        String myanswer=edittextanswer.getText().toString();              
        if(myanswer.equalsIgnoreCase(answer[index]))
        {
            //do someting
        }
        else
        {    
           //do someting
        }
```